# How to change Action Bar title color in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, styles, navigation-drawer

Am Having a Navigation Drawer in Fragment.And i want to change the action bar title color in this Fragment. For all other screens i used custom Action bar and its work fine over there. I also specified the style for Action bar title.
Here is my style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

 <!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"   parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/ActionBar_text</item>
</style>

 <style name="PoppupMenu" parent="android:Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I would recommend using a view(TextView) inside your toolbar and instead of using the default title given by the toolbar

Comment: ok, can you explain with a example? @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: not clear about your problem, does above code is working or not ?

Comment: No,not working.It does not change the actionbar text color.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the parent of CustomActionBarTheme to @style/AppTheme

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  parent="@stye/AppTheme">
```

Then change android:textColorPrimary to android:textColor

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/ActionBar_text</item>
```